Decoding function input without ABI
It may sound a bit stupid, but how does etherscan, or other similar services   decode function input without knowing it's abi? I know, that there are websites like https://www.4byte.directory/ , but if some function is not listed there, then how etherscan decodes it? It means they have a database with contract bytecodes, or they decode it by some assumptions?

As far as I know, block explorers like Etherscan primarily decode data by matching the bytecode of already verified contracts, using either full or partial matches.
Similarly, websites like 4byte.directory and openchain.xyz collect data through various methods, such as extracting signatures from verified contracts or through crowdsourced signature submissions, where developers and users can submit function signatures to the platform along with their corresponding 4-byte selectors.

So, that means if method signature is not present at these resources, I'll need to try to guess values when decoding?

Yes, if you don’t have access to the contract or interface code, ABI, or the function signature, you would need to make educated guesses about the values and data types when decoding. This can involve analyzing common encoding patterns and experimenting with different data type assumptions to interpret the input correctly.
